# Eclipse 3.7.2 + Cordova 1.9 on OSX Lion

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, cordova

I am trying to get a web app comipled for Andoid on my macbook. I have alread a number of apps published on the Apple store so I sort of know what i'm doing from a global perspective wise.

The thing is, all tutorials are based on older versions of Elicpse and Phonegap, now Cordova.

The 2 specific problems I am having are:

1. I cannot tell Eclipse to connect to an Android device over the USB. I have to run the app in the AVM simulator.
2. I managed once only to get the Hello world app to run on the simulator.

More details:

1. When i copy across the .jar and .js files from the android folder in the Cordova download, they do not show up in the directory tree on the left hand side/project browser in Eclispe; but they are there I know cz I put a copy of them there. They do show up, occasionally after a few restarts for Eclipse.
2. I cannot add the .jar file to the Build path. I right click on it but i do not get the option. Please refer to the tutorial below:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

The 2 specific questions are:

1. Will I be able to run the app on an Android device over the USB cable using mac osx and Eclipse, or i need to work on the PC for that?
2. Can you please provide some clarifications as to what are the missing steps to actually get things rolling for the latest Android 20/Elipse 3.7.2/Cordova 1.9.0 on Mac OSX Lion? any up-to-date tutorials on this regard?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes, you can run your Android device over the usb cable using mac osx and Eclipse. Two things you need to look out for are i) is the usb cable crap? One of the charger cables that came with my Samsung Galaxy S will not work, i.e. the device never get recognized with that cable but works fine with others and ii) make sure you are plugging the usb cable into the full powered usb port. One OS upgrade the MacBook got downgraded to only providing half power (or something similar) to the USB ports. If I wanted to connect multiple devices I needed to buy a USB powered hub for them.

2) http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Comment: Thanks Simon for the reply. I took the essence of it and confirm 1) and 2) now are working. The thing is that all tutorials, including the  ones shown in the links above are outdated as Eclipse is now in 4.2 and Android in 4.1. Some sleepless nights and it eventually worked.